# Function (IF) in excel

Tags: excel, function, if-statement, excel-formula, percentage

suppose i have the following notes:

- To **some** sellers is recognized a 5% bonus of the value of sales.
- However, a minimum bonus value of 250,00 is recognized to everybody.

EXERCISES

1- apply percentage format to column c.

2- write the formula to insert in column D in order to comply with the minimum condition

TABLE

```
A                B                 C                       D
            SALES VOLUME     PERCENTAGE DUE         GRAPHIC VALUE

PERSON1
PERSON2
PERSON3
```

Can someone help me ? I don't know where to start..

Comment: You may start from [here](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=excel+if+function)

Comment: How do you define “some”? Those liked by the manager? Those with sales above a certain amount? What have you tried?

Comment: @SolarMike i don't know nothing else , that's an exercise from my professor , the meaning of "some" is why i wrote to stackoverflow , cause i don't know how to determine it.

Comment: @Vitaliy Prushak i know how to use if condition , i don't know how to apply it to this exercise. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Without a clear definition of "some" it is difficult to provide a categorical answer.

How about something like this:

```
=if(b1>0,250+B1*0.05,250)
```

But if "some" is more than 300 sales, you can have:

```
=if(b1>=300,250+B1*0.05,250)
```

As for column C you can select the cells and click the % button, but I prefer to do % calculations manually ie:

```
=(B1 / sum(B$1:B$100)*100
```

assuming there are 100 entries

Answer (score 0):

Please try this solution.

[image]

The problem of who is "some" is solved by deciding arbitrarily who gets and who doesn't, simply by adding the percentage in column C. The more salient point is that whoever gets 5% shouldn't get less than the $250 everybody gets. Hence the use of the MAX() function.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the below:

VLOOKUP FORMULA:

`=VLOOKUP(A2,$H$1:$I$4,2,0)`

IF FORMULA:

`=IF(C2*B2>250,C2*B2,0)`

[image]